# If $a^n - b^n$ can be divided by $a^k - b^k$ why must $n$ be divisible by $k$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

I read that if $a^n - b^n$ can be divided by $a^k - b^k$, $n$ must be divisible by $k$. I am not sure why this is.

I had an idea but this could be completely wrong:

If the expressions can be divided, there must be an integer result of the division, that we may call $z$ - this may be an expression of some sort

Hence:

$$\frac{a^n - b^n}{a^k - b^k} = z$$

Therefore

$$a^n - b^n = z(a^k - b^k)$$

But I'm just a bit confused.

Thanks

Comment: This is false if $b=0$, for example. Another example: $a=6,b=3,n=3,k=2$.

Comment: @Wojowu but in your second example $n$ isn't divisible by $k$ - and I think the division only works when $n$ is divisible by $k$

Comment: That's precisely the point. You can't prove $n$ is divisible by $k$, because this isn't always true.

Comment: @Wojowu oh ok, but we still can say it is true for the equation to hold?

Comment: If $a^n - b^n$ is divisible by $a^k - b^k$ as polynomials in $a$ and $b$, then $n$ is divisible by $k$. It is not enough if $a$ and $b$ just happen to be some integers for which $a^n - b^n$ is divisible by $a^k - b^k$. Alternatively, if $a^n - b^n$ is divisible by $a^k - b^k$ for all integers $a > b > 0$, then $n$ is divisible by $k$.

Comment: @Magdiragdag would you mind explaining why this is please? Thanks

Comment: Is the questions about *polynomials* in $\,a,b\,$ or, rather, about *integers* that have said polynomial form?

Comment: @BillDubuque integers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theorem: If $a^k-b^k$ divides $a^n-b^n$ with $a,b>1$ *relatively prime* integers, then $k$ divides $n$.

Proof: First I claim $a^k-b^k$ and $b^k$ are also relatively prime. For if a prime $p$ divided both, then we easily see it'd also divide $a$ and $b$, contradicting coprimality of $a,b$. Now write
$$a^n-b^n=a^{n-k}(a^k-b^k)+a^{n-k}b^k+b^n=a^{n-k}(a^k-b^k)+b^k(a^{n-k}-b^{n-k}).$$
Clearly then $a^k-b^k$ divides $b^k(a^{n-k}-b^{n-k})$ and, by coprimality shown above, $a^k-b^k$ divides $a^{n-k}-b^{n-k}$.

We see that we have the same problem as before, except with exponent decreased by $k$, so property of $n$ being divisible by $k$ or not is not altered. Repeating this argument, we may assume $0\leq n<k$. If $n=0$ we are done, so assume $0<n<k$. Without loss of generality, we may also suppose $a>b$ (we can't have $a=b$ as $a,b>1$ are relatively prime), so write $a=b+c$. Expanding $(b+c)^n-b^n$ and $(b+c)^k-b^k$ it will be rather clear that the latter is larger. Hence the supposed divisibility cannot hold and we are done.